# Why doesn't CLLocationManager fail when Airplane Mode is switched on?

Tags: ios5, core-location, cllocationmanager, reachability, airplane-mode

I have a service class that is CLLocationManager's delegate. If I run the app, then open the Settings App and switch on Airplane Mode, my delegate gets nothing from CLLocationManager.

I would expect locationManager:didFailWithError to be called, but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it appears that it is possible to switch on Wi-fi while in Airplane Mode. Wi-fi is initially switched off when airplane mode is switched on, but you can switch it back on from the Settings App. This means that LocationServices are not necessarily disabled as they can still work using Wifi networks for positioning.

Comment: Good point. Testing reachability shouldn't therefore be used as a condition for activating CLLocationManager. Thanks!